# File structure in a PHP composer package with PHPSpec

Tags: php, composer-php, phpspec

I had a working composer package with a single files and a single class. So, now I'm trying to change the package so that it is more like SOLID.

I have a file structure like this...

```
PackageName.php
addresses.php
names.php
interfaces
    names.php
    addresses.php
```

When I use PHPSpec the methods in the main PackageName.php are getting validated but within one of the methods I have something like...

```
namespace blah\PackageName;

use blah\PackageName\ProcessNames;

class PackageName
{
    public function formatData($user)
    {
        $place_holders = array();
        $place_holders = ProcessNames::process_name($user, $place_holders);
        $place_holders = ProcessAddresses::process_address($user, $place_holders);
        return json_encode($place_holders);
    }
}
```

which gives the error...

> 48  ! should do the address
>           exception [err:Error("Class 'blah\PackageName\ProcessNames' not found")] has been thrown.

The composer.json is like...

```
{
    "name": "blah\PackageName",
    "description": "Format data.",
    "require": {
        "nesbot/carbon": "^1.34",
        "php": ">7.0.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpspec/phpspec": "^4.3"
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "me",
            "email": "me@emailaddress.com"
        }
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "blah\\PackageName\\": "src/",
            "spec\\blah\\PackageName\\": "spec/"
        },
        "files": {
            "src/interfaces/names.php",
            "src/names.php"
        }
    }
}
```

I can't see how to include files in the package. I'm not sure I need the "files" part on composer.json but I'm trying to figure out how to do it. Any info much appreciated.

Comment: did you forget `use` statements? Also, what's the namespace inside PackageName.php?

Comment: Thank you. Yes I did forget to use `use` statements but I am getting the same error. I updated the question with the top of the main file with the namespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the same issue someone else had today! A simple error.

Replace:

```
namespace blah\PackageName;
```

with:

```
namespace blah;
```

The full class name includes the namespace and class name. So essentially your class was actually an instance of `blah\PackageName\Packagename`

Possibly take Packagename out of the composer.json, depending on your needs, and if you change that, remember to run `composer dumpautoload`

Comment: I made the changes you suggest. In PackageName.php, all the classes and methods are showing as found in the IDE (PHPStorm) but I'm still getting `exception [err:Error("Class 'blah\ProcessNames' not found")] has been thrown.` I'm sure it's something very basic I'm not doing. Any ideas?

Comment: When I do a `shouldHaveType` I get `expected an instance of blah\ProcessNames, but got [obj:blah\Packagename].`

Comment: Take Packagename out of the composer.json namespace and run composer dumpautoload

Comment: I did this but same error, very puzzling. I'm not using the interface either. If feels like something extremely basic that I've missed out.

Comment: so its just namespace `blah` points to `src/`? Your PackageName class has just namespace blah and is sitting in `src/PackageName`?

Comment: `blah\PackageName\ProcessNames` would be in `src/PackageName/ProcessNames.php` if it's configured like my previous comment

Comment: Ahhh... filename has to be the same as the class. Much appreciated!!

Comment: Yes, just follow the directory structure and you'll be all good!